# Can not adjust UIPopupController to display images

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uipopovercontroller

In my application (code listed below), I use a popover to display a series of colors that the user can choose. These colors are used for the color of the drawing they are completing above. I am trying to modify the popover to work the same way, except for this time I would want to display images (the images are saved in the application's documents folder as png files) instead of blocks of color. Listed below is the working code for the color selector popover. ColorGrid is a UIview which contains an NSArray Colors, as well as two NSUIntegers columnCount and rowCount. I have tried to replace the items in the colors array with UIImages of the png files, as well as UIImageViews but I have not been able to get a successful result (or a compilable one). Listed below is the working code. Could anyone show me how I can change the UIColor items to the images to show them in the grid?

```
- (IBAction)popoverStrokeColor:(id)sender {
StrokeColorController *scc = [[[StrokeColorController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SelectColorController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
scc.selectedColor = self.strokeColor;
[self doPopoverSelectColorController:scc sender:sender];
}

- (void)doPopoverSelectColorController:(SelectColorController*)scc sender:(id)sender {
  [self setupNewPopoverControllerForViewController:scc];
  scc.container = self.currentPopover;
self.currentPopover.popoverContentSize = scc.view.frame.size;


 scc.colorGrid.columnCount = 2;
 scc.colorGrid.rowCount = 3;




scc.colorGrid.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                     //put the following below back in after testing
                      [UIColor blackColor],
                      [UIColor blueColor],
                      [UIColor redColor],
                      [UIColor greenColor],
                      [UIColor yellowColor],
                      [UIColor orangeColor],





                      //[UIColor purpleColor],
                     // [UIColor brownColor],
                     // [UIColor whiteColor],
                     // [UIColor lightGrayColor],
                      //[UIColor cyanColor],
                      //[UIColor magentaColor],


                      nil];
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(colorSelectionDone:) name:ColorSelectionDone object:scc];

[self.currentPopover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES]; //displays the popover and anchors it to the button
}
```

Thanks for your help. I am new to objective-c.

edit - heres the function with my attempt to insert the images instead of the colors

```
- (void)doPopoverSelectColorController:(SelectColorController*)scc sender:(id)sender {
[self setupNewPopoverControllerForViewController:scc];
scc.container = self.currentPopover;
self.currentPopover.popoverContentSize = scc.view.frame.size;

// these have to be set after the view is already loaded (which happened
// a couple of lines ago, thanks to scc.view...
scc.colorGrid.columnCount = 2;
scc.colorGrid.rowCount = 3;

//here we need to get the UIImage items to try to put in the array.
NSArray *pathforsave = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentDirectory = [pathforsave objectAtIndex:0];
//here we need to add the file extension onto the file name before we add the name to the path
//[fileName appendString:@".hmat"];
NSString *strFile = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.png"];
NSString *strFile1 = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test1.png"];
NSString *strFile2 = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test2.png"];
NSString *strFile3 = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test3.png"];
NSString *strFile4 = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test4.png"];
NSString *strFile5 = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test5.png"];

//now for the Images
UIImage *image = [ UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: strFile];
UIImage *image1 = [ UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: strFile1];
UIImage *image2 = [ UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: strFile2];
UIImage *image3 = [ UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: strFile3];
UIImage *image4 = [ UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: strFile4];
UIImage *image5 = [ UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: strFile5];

UIImageView *imageview = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image] autorelease];
[self.view addSubview:imageview];
UIImageView *imageview1 = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image1] autorelease];
[self.view addSubview:imageview1];
UIImageView *imageview2 = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image2] autorelease];
[self.view addSubview:imageview2];
UIImageView *imageview3 = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image3] autorelease];
[self.view addSubview:imageview3];
UIImageView *imageview4 = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image4] autorelease];
[self.view addSubview:imageview4];
UIImageView *imageview5 = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image5] autorelease];
[self.view addSubview:imageview5];

imageview.image = image;
imageview1.image = image1;
imageview2.image = image2;
imageview3.image = image3;
imageview4.image = image4;
imageview5.image = image5;



scc.colorGrid.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
// When attempting to add the images like this - get the error identified expected 
// after the e in image, at the end bracket. Putting a * does nothing to change the error
[image],

// When adding one of the Imageviews, i get the same error as above 
//below is how I attempted to add it
[imageView],



// 


                      nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(colorSelectionDone:) name:ColorSelectionDone object:scc];

[self.currentPopover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES]; //displays the popover and anchors it to the button
}
```

Comment: Show the code where you tried to put in image views, and what kind of errors you get when you compile.

Comment: just edited to show, i put in the comment line above the image and imageView the erros i'm getting. When putting the type before the image ( like UIImage image or UIImageView imageView - i get a warning for class method not found. and it does not work.

Comment: The last 6 lines you show aren't needed since you alloc initWithImage:, so the images are already set. It's still not clear where your errors are and what they are. Post the actual error messages.

Comment: all the error says is expected identifier. and the quick help has this, but I have not been able to do what it suggests sucessfully - 
Description: The image to use as content for the cell.
Availability iOS (2.0 and later) Deprecated: Instead use the imageView property to get UIImageView object and then get or set the encapsulated image.

Comment: i may have just found the issue - looks like its my drawRect function - will work on and re post if needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove your square brackets around image and/or imageView :

```
scc.colorGrid.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
// Not : [image] but
 image,
// or
imageView,
// Not : [imageView],
 nil];
```

Comment: thanks, this works to add the images to the array, I am still working with the drawRect function in order to display the items correctly